What happens if I do not input BSB number when I make a transaction from overseas to an Australia Bank?
I'm from Indonesia, on Friday afternoon (September 20th, 2024) I made an International transaction from Indonesia bank account to my friend's Australia Bank Account.
I transferred the money via online-banking application, I only input the SWIFT code and the receiver bank account number. I didn't aware about BSB number before, and I just realised that BSB number is something crucial to the Australia Bank's system. So now I'm really getting anxious that the transaction would go wrong as the amount of money that I sent is big enough for me.
My questions are:

Will my transaction be invalid?
If it is stated being invalid, is there a possibility that the money will bounce back to my account?

Thanks in advance.

Have you asked your bank? WHat did they say?

I asked my bank yesterday and they said that my trasaction was successful and my money alr in the receiver bank. They seemed uncertain whether this transaction will be invalid or not. Then they suggested me to ask directly to the receiver bank for further information.

OK, so if they told you it was successful already then why are you still worried it's invalid? And given that you apparently are still worried, did you speak directly to the receiver bank as suggested?

It was successful but it's not certain whether the money will be delayed or have any issues in sending to my friend's bank account due to lack of details, in this case, there's no BSB numbers (yes, it's my fault) plus I still don't know will my money be returned to my account. I have reached out the receiver bank, and they told me to wait within 3 business days. Then if my money hasn't bounced back yet I should call my bank again. Hopefully, this kind of case will be resolved soon. /sighs/
